# How to make audio using ultasonic transmitters

Tags: audio, ultrasound

I have an idea for a project that involves two ultrasonic beams colliding in mid-air to make a sound. However, I have a few questions.

1. Will this even work? I've read of this type of thing being done online, but it may have been more high-level.
2. If so, how will I create specific sounds using these transmitters? For example, if I found a car sound online, how would I convert this to ultrasonic level?
3. How can I find cheap transmitters? I've seen expensive ones and transmitter / receivers, but no cheap transmitters alone.
   I would appreciate any answers. Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Do you understand why we don't allow link-only answers? The same thing applies to comments. Without some additional text by you about why this link might be relevant (on the face of it, it is not), it's rather useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually air is always a nonlinear medium.  It's just that it is only very slightly non-linear so that unless the two interacting sound beams have very high pressure levels, the nonlinear effect is too small to observe. Water has a much higher level of nonlinearity and there are sonar systems (I know because I worked on one) that exploit this effect to generate a very low sidelobe signal at the difference frequency of two very high level higher frequency signals.  In fact, in theory, there are no sidelobes at all. However, the downside is that the efficiency of such a sonar is very low because, even in water, the nonlinear effect is small.  We used high frequency beams (at 98 and 106 kHz) with kilowatts of power to generate a difference frequency (12 kHz) beam at an equivalent level of only a few milliwatts. However the sidelobes were almost nonexistent, something to achieve otherwise.  Also, the size of the transmitting array was much smaller since the array need only transmit at the higher frequencies where the wavelength is much smaller.  These effects have been demonstrated in air but again, since air is less nonlinear than water, the efficiency is very small.

Comment: How would I make the sound beams have high pressure levels? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get two ultrasonic sounds to interact and produce an audible sound, you need to project enough energy to push the medium (air) into a nonlinear mode of operation. In a linear medium, the beams simply pass through each other without interacting.

Comment: Isn't there a beat frequency effect that can be exploited here?

Comment: @pjc50: Not really. A beat frequency is amplitude modulation on a tone you can already hear.

Comment: @Dave Not true.  A beat frequency is a linear effect.  It occurs when 2 closely spaced audio frequencies are summed in which case an apparent difference frequency (beat) can be heard and can be used to adjust one frequency equal to the other. Amplitude modulation of one tone onto another carrier tone is nonlinear and is not related to the beat effect.

Comment: @Barry: The beat frequency you hear is the *envelope* of the resulting tone that occurs when you sum two tones that are close together. Yes, you're correct in that this is not precisely what we normally call amplitude modulation -- I was being somewhat loose with the terminology. Normal AM includes a strong carrier signal, along with two sidebands. But if you suppress the carrier, you just get the two sidebands (aka, double-sideband modulation), which is exactly equivalent to the two tones the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Barry: It might be helpful to review the link that IgnacioVazquez-Abrams posted originally in order to understand why it *isn't* relevant to the question: [Wikipedia article about beat frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%28acoustics%29)